# Error on JsonElement cannot be convert to JsonObject

Tags: java, json, string, gson, jsonelement

so there is a jsonReqObj,

```
jsonReqObj = {
 "postData" : {
     "name":"abc",
     "age": 3,
     "details": {
        "eyeColor":"green",
        "height": "172cm",
        "weight": "124lb",
   }
 }
}
```

And there is a save function that will return a string. I want to use that save function, but the input parameter for the save json should be the json inside postData.

```
public String save(JsonObject jsonReqObj) throw IOException {
...
 return message
}
```

below are my code

```
JsonObject jsonReqPostData = jsonReqObj.get("postData")

String finalMes = save(jsonReqPostData);
```

But I am getting the error that

```
com.google.gson.JsonElement cannot be convert to com.google.gson.JsonObject.
```

Comment: As a side-note, it would have been useful to show *where* you got the error. Given that (I assume) it's on the line with the call to `get`, everything else (in particular the `save` method) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonObject.get` returns a `JsonElement` - it might be a string, or a Boolean value etc.

On option is to still call `get`, but cast to `JsonObject`:

```java
JsonObject jsonReqPostData = (JsonObject) jsonReqObj.get("postData");
```

This will fail with an exception if it turns out that `postData` *is* a string etc. That's probably fine. It will return `null` if `jsonReqObj` doesn't contain a `postData` property at all - the cast will succeed in that case, leaving the variable `jsonReqPostData` with a null value.

An alternative option which is probably clearer is to call `getAsJsonObject` instead:

```java
JsonObject jsonReqPostData = jsonReqObj.getAsJsonObject("postData");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to use `getAsJsonObject(String memberName)` instead of `get(String memberName)`?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri: Yup, definitely works for me! Will add that as an alternative. (I don't think it's necessarily "more accurate" but still a better option.)

Comment: Yeah with "more accurate", I meant to say more standard way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have validated your JSON file with https://jsonlint.com/ and it looks like the format is incorrect, instead of be:

```
jsonReqObj = {
    "postData": {
        "name": "abc",
        "age": 3,
        "details": {
            "eyeColor": "green",
            "height": "172cm",
            "weight": "124lb",
        }
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
{
    "postData": {
        "name": "abc",
        "age": 3,
        "details": {
            "eyeColor": "green",
            "height": "172cm",
            "weight": "124lb"
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe thats why you cant convert to an object

Note: I would put this as a comment instead as an answer, but i dont have enought reputation T_T